# add to mysql db data from json file

Tags: php, mysql, json

Is something wrong with the code?
It's not insert the data to database, i don't know what is wrong.
Can someone help me please?

Here is the php code

```html
<?php

include 'config.php';

$data = file_get_contents('programs.json');
$json = json_decode($data, TRUE);
if ($data != '' && count($json) > 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT pid FROM programs";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $transArr = array();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $transArr[] = $row["pid"];
        }
    }
    $bulk_query = '';
    $bulk_update_query = '';
    $pid = '';
    $pname = '';
    $start_date = '';
    $end_date = '';
    $logo = '';
    $short_description = '';
    $description = '';
    $ended_date = '';
    $url = '';
    $program_status = '';
    $summary = '';
    $categories = '';
    foreach ($json as $key => $jsonRow) {
        
       
        $pid = isset($jsonRow['id']) ? $jsonRow['id'] : '';
        $pname = isset($jsonRow['name']) ? $jsonRow['name'] : '';
        $start_date = isset($jsonRow['start_date']) ? $jsonRow['start_date'] : '';
        $end_date = isset($jsonRow['end_date']) ? $jsonRow['end_date'] : '';
        $logo = isset($jsonRow['logo']) ? $jsonRow['logo'] : '';
        $short_description = isset($jsonRow['short_description']) ? $jsonRow['short_description'] : '';
        $description = isset($jsonRow['description']) ? $jsonRow['description'] : '';
        $ended_date = isset($jsonRow['ended_date']) ? $jsonRow['ended_date'] : '';
        $url = isset($jsonRow['url']) ? $jsonRow['url'] : '';
        $program_status = isset($jsonRow['program_status']) ? $jsonRow['program_status'] : '';
        $summary = isset($jsonRow['summary']) ? floatval($jsonRow['summary'])  : '';
        $categories = isset($jsonRow['parent_category']['name']) ? $jsonRow['parent_category']['name'] : '';
        

        if (!in_array($pid, $transArr)) {
            $bulk_query.="('$pid','$pname','$start_date','$end_date','$logo','$short_description','$description',$ended_date,$url,'$program_status','$summary','$categories'),";
        } else {
            $sql = "UPDATE programs SET pid='$pid',name='$pname',start_date='$start_date',end_date='$end_date',"
                    . "logo='$logo',short_description='$short_description',description='$description',ended_date=$ended_date,url=$url,"
                    . "program_status='$program_status',summary='$summary',categories='$categories' WHERE pid=$pid";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
    }
    $bulk_query = rtrim($bulk_query, ",");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO programs (pid,pname,start_date,end_date,logo,short_description,description,ended_date,url,program_status,summary,categories) VALUES $bulk_query";
    $conn->query($sql);
    createFileBackup();
    echo ' Record Added';
}

?>
```

The json data im trying to insert to db

```html
[
    {
        "id": 12356,
        "name": "test",
        "start_date": "2017-06-14T21:00:00+00:00",
        "end_date": null,
        "logo": "test.png",
        "short_description": "test short_description",
        "description": "test description",
        "ended_date": null,
        "url": "http://www.test.com/",
        "program_status": "Active",
        "commissions": {
            "details": [
                {
                    "category": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Sales",
                        "cookie_length": 30,
                        "type": "sale",
                        "payout_type": "percent",
                        "tiers": [
                            {
                                "tier": {
                                    "level": 1,
                                    "action": "12.00",
                                    "subaction": "12.00",
                                    "formatted": {
                                        "action": "12,00%",
                                        "subaction": "12,00%"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "summary": {
                "percent": "12,00%",
                "flat": "-"
            },
            "tiers": {
                "count_type": "clicks",
                "amount": 1,
                "levels": []
            }
        },
        "categories": [
            {
                "parent_category": {
                    "name": "test",
                    "child_categories": [
                        {
                            "child_category": {
                                "name": "test2"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 123456,
        "name": "test",
        "start_date": "2017-06-14T21:00:00+00:00",
        "end_date": null,
        "logo": "test.png",
        "short_description": "test short_description",
        "description": "test description",
        "ended_date": null,
        "url": "http://www.test.com/",
        "program_status": "Active",
        "commissions": {
            "details": [
                {
                    "category": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Sales",
                        "cookie_length": 30,
                        "type": "sale",
                        "payout_type": "percent",
                        "tiers": [
                            {
                                "tier": {
                                    "level": 1,
                                    "action": "12.00",
                                    "subaction": "12.00",
                                    "formatted": {
                                        "action": "12,00%",
                                        "subaction": "12,00%"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "summary": {
                "percent": "12,00%",
                "flat": "-"
            },
            "tiers": {
                "count_type": "clicks",
                "amount": 1,
                "levels": []
            }
        },
        "categories": [
            {
                "parent_category": {
                    "name": "test",
                    "child_categories": [
                        {
                            "child_category": {
                                "name": "test2"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
```

And the db structure is

[image]

Comment: Be more precise. Do you get any error mressages or something? Implement some errorhandling, that could help you a lot.

Comment: there no error's in my hosting error log, can you provide me please with errorhandling code to add?

Comment: Do you get any messages? Or is the page simply blank?

Comment: Im getting this "1Record Added"

Comment: im using the same code to a similar json file and it's working great. but when i tryed to do the same with this json data i had no luck

Comment: relying on luck is not really the best way to go about your programming :-P Try debugging the code instead to see what path is being followed and what the data looks like in each moment, or analysing the JSON to see if it's valid and fits the expected structure. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php - this function could also help you see if the database is throwing any errors on either of your SQL statements.

Comment: The error was in sql query VALUES ('11249','I don't believe it')

Comment: This value 'I don't believe it', has an ' in the name how can i put it in the database as it is without problems?

Comment: i fix the issue with this $new_name = str_replace("'", "''", "$pname");  that i found online and now i can insert to db vars with apostrophes. thank you for ur help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fix the issue with this $new_name = str_replace("'", "''", "$pname"); that i found online and now i can insert to db vars with apostrophes. thank you for ur help